# Angular Material's <md-select> is not rendering correctly

Tags: html, angularjs, forms, angular-material

I am using Angular material to build a Feedback-Form.

Now I want to use `<md-select>` to choose between different titles (Mr., Mrs., ...), but it is not rendering properly.

You can see it in action [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qaWbLb?editors=1010#0).

I reviewed it with a friend, but we couldn't find the error.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you for taking the time! :)

Comment: do you tried with only material css ?

Comment: Yes it is only material-css. I am using only Theming so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed Angular Material 1.1.0-rc.5 to 1.1.0 and it works fine.

This is external cdn link:

```
https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.0/angular-material.js
```

[image: material 1.1.0 settings]